# Something is wrong with xml Tabs

Tags: android, xml, tabs

This is my Tabs in APP

[First Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxT29.png)

[Second Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JrqN.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?
My **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/header_logo" />

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

My first activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="59.908008"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="30.319100"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="8"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And second activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mapbox_compass_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idtest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Информация"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I need the design to look like this

[How i see it in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gffw.png)

I don’t understand where the problem is, I created everything from the lesson in the Russian forum (I am Russian-speaking)

Comment: I fix first screen by `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` in the **styles.xml**  but I don’t know how to design as on the third screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml file is ready

next Put this code in MainActivity.java file for adding Tab in TabHost

```
//Assign id to Tabhost.
    TabHostWindow = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    //Creating tab menu.
    TabSpec TabMenu1 = TabHostWindow.newTabSpec("First tab");
    TabSpec TabMenu2 = TabHostWindow.newTabSpec("Second Tab");

    //Setting up tab 1 name.
    TabMenu1.setIndicator("Tab1");
    //Set tab 1 activity to tab 1 menu.
    TabMenu1.setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity_1.class));

    //Setting up tab 2 name.
    TabMenu2.setIndicator("Tab2");
    //Set tab 3 activity to tab 1 menu.
    TabMenu2.setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity_2.class));

    TabHostWindow.addTab(TabMenu1);
    TabHostWindow.addTab(TabMenu2);
```

for more info visit [this](https://www.android-examples.com/android-simple-tabhost-tabwidget-example-tutorial/)

Comment: You do not understand me, I made a working class.
I need to make the logo above the tabs through imageview in the xml code, I registered it, but it does not appear at startup.

Comment: your problem is header_logo is not visible
then ues  android:src="@drawable/header_logo"  instead of app:srcCompat="@drawable/header_logo"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a separate layout file which includes the tabs and your actionBar

Comment: Himalay comment help me))